# Introducing time-dependent drive into the Hamiltonian of quantised electric circuits

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, superconductivity, cavity-qed

Suppose I have the schematic of a superconducting electric circuit composed of (quasi) lossless linear inductances and capacitances and some non-linear inductances, eg. Josephson junctions. The Hamiltonian of the circuit is derived according to [Devoret, 1997](http://qulab.eng.yale.edu/documents/reprints/Houches_fluctuations.pdf).

However this article considers the case only of a classical DC drive (so calles bias). Questions:

(1) Do you have any idea how to introduce a time-dependent drive into the system and how to consctruct the Hamiltonian of the given system? The driving may be considered classical and to begin with sinusoidal is enough.

(2) Do you have any idea how to treat the a non-classical drive, ie. the energy from the generators into the cicrcuit is coming in the form of single photons well separated in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single photon mode is described by a creation operator. The problem is not complicated and really generic in bosonic problems.

How to include the driving is just a matter of taste. Suppose your circuit is described by the degrees of freedom $x$ and $p$ (say position and momentum). A force $f$ would be added as a term $x\cdot f$ in the Hamiltonian for instance (modulo all the required integral / most certainly in time for lumped elements).

For a circuit it's the same, except $p$ and $x$ are usually flux/charge and/or current/voltage or something else, but certainly less intuitive than position and momentum. It means you can find a coupling with either $p$ and/or $x$, so either something like $f\cdot x$ or $f\cdot p$ (modulo problems of dimensions).

To make it time-dependent is trivial, say $f\left(t\right)\cdot x$ is the coupling term in the Hamiltonian.

To quantise the coupling, you should impose a dynamics of this extra degree of freedom. For instance, if it's a photon mode, you can discuss this degrees of freedom as an oscillator, say $H_{\text{photon}}=p^{2}/2m+\omega^{2}x^{2}=\hbar\omega a^{\dagger}a$ and you make a coupling position-position, momentum-position, etc... depending on the nature of the coupling (inductive / capacitive / mixed ...)

So for instance suppose your system is a simple LC circuit, so it corresponds to a harmonic oscillator, say with creation/annihilation operators $b$ and $b^{\dagger}$. Further suppose that the photon mode is harmonic as well, and that the coupling is position-position like, then you have something like

$$H\sim\hbar\omega a^{\dagger}a+\hbar\Omega b^{\dagger}b+g\left(b+b^{\dagger}\right)\left(a+a^{\dagger}\right)$$

with $\Omega$ the LC resonance-frequency and $g$ a coupling constant (to simplify).

Comment: I have several  questions: why is a force added as $x \cdot f$ (sorry, I know it's basic quantum mechanics). Second: what do you mean by "modulo all the required integral / most certainly in time for lumped elements" and  "modulo problems of dimensions"?

Comment: Problem of dimension: a current is in Ampère, a voltage is in Volt, so the constant has to be adapted to each case, and $p$ and/or $x$ correctly identified. Modulo all the integrals: usually a Hamiltonian is defined as $H=\int dt h(t)$, with a time-dependent function $h(t)$ which I used as a "Hamiltonian". One writes the "force" as $f\cdot x$ since, in the equation of motion, it appears then as $\ddot{x}=f$, see a basic lecture in Hamiltonian mechanics (nothing to do with a lecture in quantum mechanics, wikipedia is a good source to start with). Do not hesitate if you need more details :-)

Comment: But if you make a Hamiltonian of this form (as far as I know this is of the form of the Jaynes-Cummings model) doesn't it simply describe two coupled photon modes? I don't see why one of them would function as a photon source to the other. This way photons may go from each one into the other. Moreover I would be really grateful if you could recommend a good book on the subject. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user3237992 A really good book (and one I know) on the topic is the one by Cohen-Tannoudji / Dupont-Roc / Grynberg titled Photon-atom interaction, or something like that (I know only the one in french ; be careful, there are two books by Cohen-Tannoudji with the same title, the interesting one is by the three above authors). Indeed the Hamiltonian I gave is a simple one for illustration, it describes the coupling between two harmonic modes. The key point is (always) the coupling. Above I gave it in the quantum picture, for two quantum systems. A classic source would be treated as classical.

Comment: It is not a Jaynes-Cimmung model, since this later would couple a bosonic mode with a fermionic one, something like $H=\sigma_{z}+\sigma_{x}\cdot(b+b^{\dagger})+\omega bb^{\dagger}$, see again Wikipedia about Jaynes-Cumming, or the above cited book by C-T, D-R and Grynberg. An other book on quantum optics is the one by Wall and Millburn, with all the developments by Glauber. About circuits, there are no good book as far as I know, but it exists a famous lecture by Devoret title "fluctuations in (quantum) circuits". See  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141486/16689 about this lecture.

Comment: Funny thing is that this is also my question :D However thank you very much for your answers, I will surely look into these books.